# software to manage hardware drivers?

Tags: drivers

I am looking for something that will be able to scan the drivers on my computer and tell me if any of them are out of date.

I've seen lots of ads for this type of things and most of them seem pretty sketchy.  My computer has a lot of hardware - and it would be nice if there was an easy way to make sure I'm not missing anything when I update the software.

Comment: Perhaps the make of computer and operating system would help.  Many vendors like Lenovo and HP offer this tool

Comment: why do you feel you need to do this?

Comment: Windows Updates does a pretty good job of this.

Comment: I agree with Keltari. I've *never* seen the need for such programs  TBH. Do it manually; is it that hard?

Comment: I assume he has non-MS-hardware and thus wants up-to-date drivers.

Comment: @BroScience Windows updates are definitely different from driver updates. But in general, I agree, there isn't really a good way to do this besides manually; there aren't applications that can get data from every hardware vendor in a unified way.

Comment: @BroScience I have seen Windows update offer drivers (usually Video) which result in issues.  Many vendors like Lenovo,Dell and HP have a tool to assure you get the proper say nVidia driver.  Just becaue it is an nVidia chipset does not nmean the driver from the nVidia site will work.  See Lenoveo Thinkvantage System update as an example.

Comment: @MarcusChan - Windows Update absolutely provides drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try uniblue powersuite. It is the only success I have had when in deep trouble. If there is something out there they will find it.

I got an acer 10 to run windows 7 using powersuites driver updates. Everybody said this couldn't be done